# Последовательное запись в файл, после обращения на сервер

Tags: java, android

Имеется код:

```
 FILENAME= "file";
            url = new URL("1231");
            new ParseTask(url,FILENAME).execute();
            url = new URL("1231");
            FILENAME="file1";
            new ParseTask(url,FILENAME).execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
     public class ParseTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String resultJson = "";
    private URL url;
    public String file;

    public ParseTask(URL url, String file) {
        this.url = url;
        this.file=file;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // получаем данные с внешнего ресурса
        try {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            resultJson = buffer.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultJson;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
        try {
            // отрываем поток для записи
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    openFileOutput(FILENAME, MODE_PRIVATE)));
            // пишем данные
            bw.write(strJson);
            // закрываем поток
            bw.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Он почему-то работает только с последним файлом, как сделать, чтобы он с обоими файлами работал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вся проблема, что вы используете значение глобальной переменной `FILENAME` в методе `onPostExecute`.
Соответственно, в асинхронном мире вызов этого метода происходит не моментально (асинхронно), и глобальная переменная в момент вызова метода содержит уже значение `file1`.

У вас же есть поле класса с именем файла, вот его и надо использовать:

```
// отрываем поток для записи
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                openFileOutput(this.file, MODE_PRIVATE)));
```